# Card carousel with stacking in CSS with react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

[image: carousel]I want to create something like this .
With Cards appear like stacked on each other and also three dots to toggle them.Can anyone tell how can i implement this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can help you with issues but you need to provide code that you've tried. We won't write code for you. Google has plenty of answers for your question as is. Please read the Help section to learn how to ask a proper question.

Comment: I am looking for something similar. There is an example here but there may be better alternatives out there? https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/PobmGme

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific enough and it gives the impression that you want other people to do your job for you, so that's probably why you're receiving downvotes. But if you are asking like how one might approach such a task, one possible way I can think of is something like this:

- Make each card a component with an id,
- In your container component's state, keep (1) the list of all ids and (2) the
  active/current id
- Match the ids with the little dots so that each dot will be linked to a card (for onClick events and also for styling)
- Display the card with active id, and also implement onClick events for the dots  (and possibly swipe events for mobile too) so that each dot will activate their linked card and that's how you'll be able to switch between cards
- The visual bit of making it look like they are stacked cards may be done only in CSS, or a combination of both JS and CSS, depending on how you'd like to animate the card switches etc.

But again, that's only one possible approach among many. Regardless if you'd like to go with this approach or choose some other, the actual implementation of it will be up to you.